# Stabilizing controls in linear quadratic regulator

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control, dynamic-programming, linear-control

I am studying a linear quadratic control problem with discounting. For $\gamma \in (0,1)$, $Q \succeq 0$ and $R \succ 0$ and linear dynamics $s_{t+1}=As_t + B a_t$, let the total cost starting in state $s_0$ and using the control $a_t = \theta s_t$ be:

$$
J_{\theta}(s_0) = \sum_{t=0}^\infty \gamma^t \left( s_t^\top Q s_t + a_t^\top R a_t \right) = s_0^\top \left[ \sum_{t=0}^\infty \gamma^t ((A+B\theta)^t)^\top (Q + \theta^\top R \theta) (A+B\theta)^t \right]
$$

Assume $\theta$ to be a stabilizing control, i.e. $\rho(A+B\theta) < 1$. I want to show the following:

Let $\theta'$ be another linear control such that $J_{\theta'}(s_0) < J_{\theta}(s_0)$ for all starting states $s_0$. Then, is it true that $\theta'$ is also stabilizing. That is, is $\rho(A+B\theta') < 1$? If so, how does one prove this kind of result? The discount factor $\gamma$ is stumping me.

Edit: What I am studying here is called Policy Iteration in dynamic programming. Also assuming the optimal controller, $\theta^*$ is stable. Policy iteration produces an 'improved policy' in terms of costs from every state but I am not sure if this policy is stable.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true that $\theta'$ has to be a stabilizing state feedback controller. This would even not be true without the discounting factor $\gamma^t$.

For example consider

$$
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0.5
\end{bmatrix}, \quad
B = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix},
$$

$$
Q =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}, \quad
R = 1, \quad
s_0 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

It can be shown that $\theta =\begin{bmatrix}-2 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ is a stabilizing controller and would yield some positive total cost. However, if you would use $\theta' =\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ one would get that the total cost is zero.

Things don't have to change if one would also include the constraint that $(A,Q)$ is detectable. For example consider the following scalar system with $A=2$, $B=1$, $Q=1$, $R=1$ and $\gamma=¼$. Because the system is scalar by using the [geometric series](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html) the cost function can be simplified to

\begin{align}
J_\theta(s_0) &= y_0^2 (Q + \theta^2 R) \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\gamma (A + B\,\theta)^2\right)^k, \\
&= \frac{y_0^2 (Q + \theta^2 R)}{1 - \gamma (A + B\,\theta)^2}, \\
&= \frac{y_0^2 (1 + \theta^2)}{1 - ¼(2 + \theta)^2}.
\end{align}

In order for the geometric series to converge it should hold that $|¼(2 + \theta)^2|<1$ which implies $-4<\theta<0$. It can be shown that in that interval $J_\theta(s_0)$ is minimized at $\theta^*=¼(1-\sqrt{17})\approx -0.78$. It can be noted that $\rho(A+B\,\theta^*)\approx 1.22 \nless1$ and since $\theta^*$ is the minimizer of $J_\theta(s_0)$ it follows that any stabilizing $\theta$ yields a larger value for $J_\theta(s_0)$.

Comment: Hi @kwin van der Veen, I am assuming $\theta'$ to be such that it improves the cost from all states, not just a particular $s_0$. For example, let's assume the state space to be entire $\mathbb{R}^2$ or a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @Jalaj my second counter example should then still hold. I suspect that for higher order systems one can also come up with similar counter examples. However, for higher order systems the cost function is not as easy to evaluate.

Comment: The second example you give has an unstable optimal controller. Consider the situation where I have a stable controller and then I come up with another controller that improves costs from all states (I am coming from the Dynamic programming perspective where this is called 'Policy Iteration/Improvement'). It can be shown that Policy Iteration improves costs from all starting states. What is unclear if the 'improved policy' is stable.

Comment: @Jalaj it doesn't have to be that the improved cost function yields a stable control policy as shown by my second example.

Comment: But I think the argument you give for that is that the optimal controller is not stable. I am assuming there exists an optimal control which is stable.